# How to control acceleration and de-acceleration in my C# game

Tags: c#, xna

I am building a driving game. The view is a perspective one and the player's perspective is from behind the car which is driving forward. When the car is driving forward, all the environment around it moves downwards and scales (This is looking quite good now) which gives the impression of the car moving forward. Now, I want to have some realistic driving controls, so that the car builds up speed and then slows down gradually when the up arrow is released. Currently, I call all the move functions for several sprites when the up arrow is pressed. I am looking for a way to control this so that the functions are not called as often when the car is slow etc etc. The code I have so far is:

```
   protected void Drive()
    {
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            MathHelper.Clamp(++TruckSpeed, 0, 100);
        }
        else
        {
            MathHelper.Clamp(--TruckSpeed, 0, 100);
        }

        // Instead of using the condition below, I want to use the TruckSpeed
        // variable some way to control the rate at which these are called 
        // so I can give the impression of acceleration and de-acceleration.

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            // Lots of update calls in here
        }
   }
```

I thought this should be easy but for some reason, I cannot make any sense out of it. Would really appreciate some help here! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First suggestion, don't use `++` and `--`. Make your `TruckSpeed` increase at a rate multiplied by the `Delta Time`. This means that your acceleration and deceleration will work the same on slower and faster computers and will be independent of frame rate hickups. You can also have different increase and decrease rates for better control over your gameplay.

Something along the lines of:

```
protected void Drive(GameTime gameTime) // Pass your game time
{
    KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    {
        TruckSpeed += AccelerationRatePerSecond * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }
    else
    {
        TruckSpeed -= DecelerationRatePerSecond * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }
    MathHelper.Clamp(TruckSpeed, 0, 100);
    ...
```

Also, you can probably replace

```
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
```

by

```
if (TruckSpeed > 0)
```

It's probably simpler to attach the camera to your model and move that in the environment instead of moving your entire environment around the Truck though...

Comment: "It's probably simpler to attach the camera to your model and move that in the environment instead of moving your entire environment around the Truck though..." - Well-stated, sir.  +1

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the game is 2D so attaching a camera and moving through the environment is not something I can do. Also, if I add (TruckSpeed > 0), doesn't that just mean that the truck will always be "moving"? I want to control the rate at which the update methods are called so the truck can "move" at different speeds. Thanks

Comment: @Chris within a 2D scene you can always move your "viewport" and render the appropriate sprites. As for `TruckSpeed > 0`... if you decelerate enough your speed will reach `0` (your Clamp) and you won't move anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help emartel. I have made changes to the way in which I increase and decrease the acceleration values. I am still stuck with the TruckSpeed > 0 though. If I use TruckSpeed to control how often I call the update methods for objects then what is the difference between 1 and 99 for example? Surely by having if(TruckSpeed > 0) { ... } I will only ever have two states (Driving with not acceleration or not driving at all)

Comment: Oh! But you should use your TruckSpeed to determine by HOW MUCH everything moves, I think that's what's missing in your code (but we don't see how you actually implemented the scrolling)

Comment: Ohhhhh! Sorry, I see. I have been thinking of this differently! Perhaps I was just subconsciously being lazy in hoping I could just change the rate at which I call the update methods! :/ I am going to have to change all of my classes now but that's not a problem as it does seem more sensible. Thank you emartel. Sorry for the confusion here :/ (Long day and too much coffee - time for rest!)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and correct approach is to separate keyboard control from physics. You want acceleration to be measured in change/per-unit-of-time not change/per-button-click. Than on each time iteration you need to modify speed according to time passed since last update...

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is not linear. As such, I would recommend not to use the ++ or -- operators. Instead call a function that calculates the change in velocity over time (delta V)/time. If you want a true feeling of acceleration you might think about something to that effect.